# How does WolframAlpha solve this recursion?

Tags: functional-equations, recursion

I have the following recursion:
$$x_n=\frac{n-1}{n}x_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor.$$
[WolframAlpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x_%7Bn%7D%3D%5B%28n-1%29%2Fn%5Dx_%7Bn-1%7D%20%2B%20floor%28n%2F2%29%2Fn) a solution to this recursion as
$$x_n=\frac{C_1+\left\lceil\frac{1-n}{2}\right\rceil^2-\left\lceil\frac{1-n}{2}\right\rceil+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor^2+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}{2n},$$
for some arbitrary parameter $C_1$. How is this solution found? Moreover, is this solution unique?

Comment: With recurrence relations you need to specify for what $n$ the relation applies, and possibly also initial conditions. If the relation here applies only for $n\geq 2$ then the constant $C_1$ appears because the initial term $x_1$ has not been specified. If the relation applies for $n=1$ as well however, then the sequence is fully determined for $n\geq 1$ regardless of what the previous terms are, as $x_1 = 0 x_n + 0 = 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set $y_n = n x_n$ then the recursion is $y_n = y_{n-1} + \left\lfloor\frac n2\right\rfloor$ which may in turn be simplified by considering even and odd $n$ separately.

All you need to know then is that $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n^2+n}2$.  The parameter $C_1$ appears because no initial value for the recursion is given.

As for the question of uniqueness, once you are given, e.g. $x_0$ or $x_1$, the whole sequence is fixed, so the correctness of the solution implies it is the unique solution.